# How to debug/set breakpoint for JavaScripts in HTML or PHP?

Tags: javascript, debugging, joomla

For standalone .js files, we can easily inspect it in "source" panel of development tools and set breakpoint for them. But I often come across those js snippets that are in script tags in HTML, how do I set breakpoint or debug them?

Moreover, in Joomla, some js are written in custom HTML modules, and if there are some errors in the code, unlike for other standalone js files, where chrome comes up with clickable line of error, in this case chrome will only report something like "index.php/:54", and when clicked, it doesnt take you to the error point, and the supposed 'line number' itself is totally not helping.

So, for these two scenarios, how do I debug the codes? And also, in the second scenario, what excatly does the number means?

Comment: You should be able to inspect the code using your browser. In chrome you access the dev tools by 'f12'. check out this page https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers also give you the option of placing a single line into your script, containing:

```
debugger;
```

Which effectively places a breakpoint, hitting it stops the JS execution and brings up the developer console's debugging tools.

Of course, you can't have this in production code, but it's a great tool for development.

**Edit**: on second thought, I just tried placing a breakpoint in an html-inlined script of stackoverflow in Chrome 41, and it worked. Are you sure it doesn't work for you?:) (Maybe you didn't look under the right source in the sources panel?)

Comment: Good to know. But sometimes I have no control over the snippets. For instance, let's say I am just trying to understand how a stie's javascript works, to do that, I have to insert some break points, but of course I can't edit the source.

Comment: @shenkwen see my edit - Chrome allows me to put breakpoints into inline scripts, are you sure yours doesnt?

Comment: I see what you mean, yes for stackoverflow, I can see the whole HTML in SOURCE panel, but for my sites that are mostly built with joomla, things are not like this. Take my current object http://tt.fbcwinterretreat.org for instance, on source panel, under 'tt.fbcwinterretreat.org' section, besides other subsections,I can only see a `(index)`. And when  click it, It just show s a blank area at where the codes are supposed to display, well not entirely blank, there is a warning sign at 4th line, which makes things a little funny and annoying.  Screen shot : [link](http://xrsand.com/bin/blank.png)

Comment: @shenkwen, scroll down in your screenshot, the script tags are present :) (lines 45-50 and 1015- on)

Comment: Thank you I didn't notice that. But there are still problems regarding this issue. I deliberately put some erroneous javascript into one of my custom HTML modules. If you look at the page tt.fbcwinterretreat.org now, you will see an error. However, chrome indicates this error occurs in line 990 (`(index):990`). When clicked, it brings you to another blank area, where line 990 has nothing in it. It is very confusing!

Answer (score 0):

i hope it will help u..

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>

<p>
Activate debugging in your browser (Chrome, IE, Firefox) with F12, and select "Console" in the debugger menu.
</p>

<script>
a = 5;
b = 6;
c = a + b;
console.log(c);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```